# Android camera2 - devices supporting depth output

Tags: android, depth, point-clouds, android-camera2

I saw the following in the Android documentation for camera2 from API level 23:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#DEPTH16

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD

However I could not find any practical examples of those. Are there any Android devices that support this API ?

Many thanks,

Guillaume

Comment: I think at that time it was a mobile in Tango project. Which is not sell well. But currently now it might be all ARCore supported device

Answer (score 0):

At this time Oct 2019, I know HUAWEI P30 series and MATE20 series support output of DEPTH_16 image.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.